# Xamarin.Forms problems sending large picture over HttpClient SendAsync in Json format

Tags: json, xamarin, httpclient, xamarin.forms, sendasync

from my Xamarin.Forms app I'm sending a picture and other fields to the server using HttpClient in Json format.
If I send a little picture I've got with my front camera it's working fine, if I send a larger picture I've got with the rear camera it doesn't work and I always get an exception: "Excepional error".

I tried to create the same code in a windows form application and it's working fine also with large images, but not from my App.

I have already modified on the server web.config to increase json content size:

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
```

Can someone help ?! Thanks!!

This is the code on my app:

```
public async static Task<MyAppDataModels.Common.WsResponse> PostPhotoFromUser(int catalogItemId, int objReferenceId, int languageId, byte[] fileContent)
    {
        MyAppDataModels.Common.WsResponse MyResponse = new MyAppDataModels.Common.WsResponse();
        try
        {                
            HttpClient MyHttpClient = new HttpClient();
            MyHttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(520);
            MyHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("{0}/Application/ApplicationPostPhotoFromUser", MyAppSettings.ServerApiUrl));
            MyHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            MyHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            MyHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Clear();
            MyHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptCharset.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("utf-8"));
            HttpRequestMessage MyWsRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, MyHttpClient.BaseAddress);

            dynamic MyObjData = new JObject();
            MyObjData["CatalogItemId"] = catalogItemId;
            MyObjData["ObjReferenceId"] = objReferenceId;
            MyObjData["UserId"] = string.Empty;
            MyObjData["LanguageId"] = languageId;
            MyObjData["Picture"] = fileContent;

            string MySerializedPostedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObjData);
            MyWsRequest.Content = new StringContent(MySerializedPostedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage MyWsResponse = await MyHttpClient.SendAsync(MyWsRequest, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
            MyWsResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var MyContentResponse = await MyWsResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            MyResponse.ResponseId = MyAppConstants.Constants.ResponseCode.Successfull;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MyResponse.ResponseId = MyAppConstants.Constants.ResponseCode.ErrorWhileProcessingRequest;
            MyResponse.ResponseErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
        return MyResponse;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: what app is this not working on? iOS or Android?

Comment: I'm using Xamarin.Forms and the code it's inside PCL, in this case where I have the problem I'm running the app on Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the stacktrace,

> System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError

means that the server responded with some 40x error, maybe 401 (Acess Denied) or something similar.

you can wrap your call in a:

```
try
{
}
catch(WebException ex){
}
```

then check the exceptions **Status** and cast the exception's response like that:

```
((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription
```

to get more info about what has gone wrong on the server.

**EDIT:**
Because you're uploading large files, you can resolve the "maximum request length exceeded exception", you need to modify your server's (ASP.NET for example) web.config file to accept large request size:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="50000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: From the TryCatch I got this message: 
ExceptionMaximum request length exceeded. at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_InputStream() at ApplicationPostPhotoFromUser(HttpRequestMessage httRequestMessage) in D:\xxx\ApplicationController.vb:line 267. 
In this line I have the following code where I read the request content: 
Dim MyStreamReader As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream)

Comment: please check the updated answer, you need to increase the max request size on your server config.

Comment: I added this line in my web.config and restarted IIS, but now I get 500 (Internal server error)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, maybe you can debug your server side method that accepts the uploaded images and see the exact exception details.

Comment: I've been able to solve the 500 (Internal server error) then I got an error on JSON JavaScriptSerializer length of the string which exceeded the value set on the maxJsonLength property. I have increased this value on the code (MyJs.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue) and now it's working!! MANY thanks !!!!!

Comment: Great, I'm glad to hear that. Good luck